# Makefile all command

Tags: makefile

I'm in the process of learning c, and trying to get my head around makefiles. I'm following Learn C the Hard way.

On exercise 2, the extra credit states to make a command in my makefile that allows me to compile my .c file by typing just "make".

My makefile is:

```
CLAGS=-WALL -g

all: ex1

clean:
    rm ex1
```

This works - i.e. typing make clean removes the ex1 file, and typing make compiles ex1.c into an executable.

However, I'm confused as to why in the clean command, rm ex1 has to be indented on the line below clean, but for the all command, if I indent ex1 on the line below all, it throws an error. Why is this?

My other question is - how exactly does this work? Is all just a keyword that goes along the lines of "when make (with no command) is typed, do this"?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no relation to C (`CFLAGS` is actually not the point here) or C++.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This:

```
clean:
    rm ex1
```

is a **rule**. This rule contains a single **command**, `rm ex1`. The command is a shell command. Each command in the rule must be indented with a `TAB` character (or Make will get confused).

This:

```
all: ex1
```

is a rule without commands. The "ex1" here is not a command, it is a **prerequisite**.

This:

```
all:
    ex1
```

is an invalid rule, because it contains an invalid command; "ex1" is not a valid shell command. (Just try it on the command line if you don't believe me.)

If you execute Make without specifying a target (by typing "make"), Make will use the default target, which is usually the first target in the makefile. (There are some exceptions you need not worry about now.) By convention, "all" is the name of rule that does most of what you want done, and it is often the default target; this is a convention, not something built into Make.

Comment: Thank you, nice and simple. Last concern - when typing `make`, it would compile ex1, but how does it know to compile ex1 when I've not typed `gcc ex1 ex1.c` as a rule below all?

Comment: @F.Tahir: The "all" rule has "ex1" as a prerequisite, so Make looks for a way to build (or rebuild) `ex1` before executing the "all" rule. There is no explicit rule for building `ex1` in this makefile, but there is a file `ex1.c`, and Make knows how to build `foo` from `foo.c` without being told.

Answer (score 1):

Because `ex1` is a target that defaults to calling `cc` over a `ex1.c` file, you could make `all:` a target like this too

```
all:
    $(CC) -o $(EXECUTABLE) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) ex1.c
```

don't copy and paste this, because i've used spaces and `Makefiles` require tabs instead.

An even better way would be to create an object files target and compiling only changed files while linking in the other target, like this

```
CC      = gcc
CFLAGS  = -Wall -Wextra -Werror
LDFLAGS = # empty if you are not going to link to any library
OBJ     = ex1.o
PROGRAM = ex1

all: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(PROGRAM) $(OBJ)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

clean:
    rm -fv *.o $(PROGRAM)
```

now you would easily add more `.c` files by just appending them to the `OBJ` macro, like this

```
OBJ = ex1.o ex2.o ... exn.o
```

Comment: So why doesn't it work if I type ex1 on the line below? What exactly is the difference?

Comment: You mean `make ex1`? It's not an explicit rule. [Read this for more information](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_10.html).

Comment: If I do `all : make ex1` where make ex1 is on a newline, then this works, but if I do `all: ex1` where `ex1` is on a new line then it throws an error when typing make.  The error is make: ex1: Command not found
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 127.

The thing that confuses me most is how the makefile knows what command to pull up when I type just make (is it by default the first command in the makefile?)

Comment: @F.Tahir: Yes, the first *rule* in the makefile is the default *rule*. By convention, the rule that does most of what you want done is called `all`, and is the first rule.

Comment: Okay, that clears most of my confusion up, thanks. Still unsure why the all command refuses to work when its indented like the clean command.

Comment: You can't call a rule as if it was a command. When you put at the right of `: ` it means that the current rule depends on it. For example `all: ex1` means that `all` depends on `ex1`, so `ex1` is executed first.